# Rapidminer, splitting string

Tags: rapidminer

I want to split strings (deleting cointain of ()) in form

```
eye of vichy, the (l'oeil de vichy)
```

to

```
eye of vichy, the
```

I need to use regular expression operator "Replace".

Comment: Show us what you have tried.

Answer (score 0):

Using the `Replace` operator, set the `replace what` parameter to `(.*)\(.*\)(.*)` and set the `replace by` parameter to `$1$2`.